# Where can I download with a link the locale file for french Canadian in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, local

I'm trying to find the link of a CDN to the local js file for Angular JS for french Canadian. I found one site, but the the list is really wrong and I'm really not shure which one to take... (https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-i18n)

I think it's angular-locale_fr-ca.js, but I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local js file for Angular JS for french Canadian is:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.4.2/angular-locale_fr-ca.js